# HTTP error when installing pytorch

Tags: amazon-s3, pytorch

I use ubuntu14.04, without GPU.
when I install pytorch in anaconda(I type command just as pytorch.org says),things always get wrong,like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/zhanglu/anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    pytorch:     0.1.9-py36_2 soumith
    torchvision: 0.1.7-py36_1 soumith

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:       4.3.8-py36_0         --> 4.3.13-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

pytorch-0.1.9- 100% |################################| Time: 0:02:49   1.44 MB/s
pytorch-0.1.9- 100% |################################| Time: 0:05:52 692.97 kB/s
pytorch-0.1.9- 100% |################################| Time: 0:01:15   3.23 MB/s


CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
ConnectionError(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.",),)


CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
ConnectionError(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.",),)


CondaError: CondaHTTPError: HTTP None None for url <None>
Elapsed: None

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
ConnectionError(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.",),)

----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried many times, but every time error occurs in the same step.
I'm looking forward your answers,thanks very very much for your help!!!

Comment: Have you tried googling this? There seems to be very little information to answer this question. You could try going through [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/3323) post and see whether you can find something that can help you. If you have logged into anaconda cloud then you can log out as it has helped other people resolve HTTP errors

Answer (score 0):

Please update to the latest version of Navigator.

Open a terminal (on Linux or Mac) or the Anaconda Command Prompt (on windows)
and type

$ conda update anaconda-navigator